# How to read event viewer in windows 7 or XP using python

Tags: python

I wanted read event viewer log file using event ID in Windows 7

Comment: Good idea! (Translation: What's the question? What have you tried?, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer & sample code:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577499-windows-event-log-viewer/

But you will need to instal pywin32 extension, you can found it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

without an extension, you can't do that, because there is no native support for win32 api's.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to get particular EventID, How can read the event log